# JAR: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, gradle

Did write Java Class for Connection to Hive and did make gradle task to build JAR with All dependencies

```
task Hive(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'ru.prometheus.nodeexporters.Hive'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-Node_Exporter'
//    from('src/main/java') {
//        include 'resources/*'
//    }
    from {
        configurations.runtime.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    with jar
}
```

did execute task

```
12:55:46: Executing task 'Hive'...


> Task :Hive:compileJava
Note: C:\Servers\Repository\PrometheusNodeExporters\Hive\src\main\java\ru\prometheus\nodeexporters\Hive.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Servers\Repository\PrometheusNodeExporters\Hive\src\main\java\ru\prometheus\nodeexporters\Hive.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :Hive:processResources
> Task :Hive:classes
> Task :Hive:Hive

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 26s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
12:56:13: Task execution finished 'Hive'.
```

after did check JAR

[image]

Main class did exist, BUT if did try to execute returned error

```
c:\Servers\Repository\PrometheusNodeExporters\Hive\build\libs>java -jar Hive-Nod
e_Exporter-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class ru.prometheus.nodeexporters.Hive
```

How solve this "simple" problem?

Project on [GitHub](https://github.com/drno-reg/PrometheusNodeExporterHive.git)

Comment: can you start it like that: `java -jar Hive-Nod
e_Exporter-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ru.prometheus.nodeexporters.Hive`?

Comment: c:\Server\Repositories\Projects\PrometheusNodeExporterHive\build\libs>java -jar PrometheusNodeExporterHive-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ru.prometheus.nodeexporter.Hive
Error: Could not find or load main class ru.prometheus.nodeexporter.Hive, same error